# Does Xcode instrument works on real Apple Watch device?

Tags: ios, profiling, instruments, apple-watch, watchos

Do Xcode instruments work on WatchOS? It shows the error 
"Waiting for com.foo.fooapp.watchkitextension
Please take appropriate action to initiate the launch of 'com.foo.fooapp.watchkitextension'".

It doesn't work on real devices.
The real device environment is Xcode8.2 beta, iPhone 10.1.1, WatchOS3.1.

It's a general question, but I have no clue about where can I find the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Instruments debugger (e.g. Time Profiler), you want to select the Apple Watch device > WatchKit Extension app.  Then press the red record button to attach the debugger.

It won't work if you attach to the iPhone device, even though WatchKit extension shows up in that list.

Comment: You're right! Still very interesting that "WatchKit extension" is not the default target. And sometimes it fails for a unknown reason.